# Unable to establish debug connection for tizen .NET with Samsung Galaxy on Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, tizen, samsung-galaxy

I try to debug my tizen .NET application on my *Samsung Galaxy Watch Active 2*, Platform: *wearable-5.5.0.1* with *Visual Studio 2019*.
I can successfully build the application but when I try to run the debugger of Visual Studio 2019 it tells me that it's unable to establish a connection to CLRDBG:

[image: Visual Studio Screenshot after running Debugger]

I am connected to my watch, I created a Samsung certificate and signed my .tpk with it and I have also installed all the [recommended workloads and plugins](https://developer.samsung.com/tizen/Galaxy-Watch/installation/installation-on-windows.html) for visual studio to run my application.
The debugging log just says:

```
Starting: "c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\0fvmyk5j.31p\NetCat.exe" 127.0.0.1 4712
"c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2019\community\common7\ide\extensions\0fvmyk5j.31p\NetCat.exe" exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I can't find anything helpful regarding this error message. Has anyone of you an idea what could cause this issue?

Comment: Did you found solution?

Comment: Any luck or solution?

Comment: The only "workaround" was to repeatedly clicking the play button after a failed attempt. After some retries it often worked..

Answer (score 2):

This error is about Tizen certificate validation.

1. open Tizen certificate manager
2. select Samsung type
3. Select your device type
4. Set a name for certificate profile
5. Next
6. select an author name and password
7. Log in to your samsung account
8. Next
9. Next
10. **Most important part is to Connect your device through tizen device manager that it detects individual DUID automatically**

[image]

Comment: your suggestion works but i would extend that if there is already existing instance with the difference certificate installed. uninstall and start debugging